# Find the number of natural solutions for $x_1 +x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$, with $ x_i \notin 3\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, generating-functions

Find the number of natural solutions for $$x_1 +x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n,$$ with the constraints $x_i \notin 3\mathbb{N}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k$.

***My Attempt:***

the generating function of the equation is: 
$f(x) =(x+x^2)(1+x^3 +x^6+\cdots +x^{3k} +\cdots)$

Now I know that for $g(x) = 1+x+x^2+\dots +x^k +\cdots = \ \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k =  \frac{1}{1-x}$

does that mean that $f(x) =(x+x^2)(1+x^3 +\cdots +x^{3k} +\cdots)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (x^{3k})\cdot(x+x^2) = \frac{(x+x^2)}{1-x^{3k}}$

But How do I Continue with my function?

Comment: It wouldn't be $3k$ in the denominator anymore, just $3$.

Comment: what is a set $3 \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It seems that in the statement of the problem $k$ is a certain number. However in your solution attempt it is obviously assumed to be arbitrary. What is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function is
$$
\left(\frac{x+x^2}{1-x^3}\right)^k\tag1
$$
since each variable can take values in the exponents of
$$
\frac{x+x^2}{1-x^3}=x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^7+x^8+\dots\tag2
$$
Compute the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^n\right]\left(\frac{x+x^2}{1-x^3}\right)^k
&=\left[x^{n-k}\right]\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x^3}\right)^k\\
&=\left[x^{n-k}\right]\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{k}{i}x^i\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{-k}{j}x^{3j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{k}{n-k-3j}(-1)^j\binom{-k}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{k}{n-k-3j}\binom{j+k-1}{j}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
That is, the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1)$ is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}3\right\rfloor}\binom{k}{n-k-3j}\binom{j+k-1}{j}\tag4
$$

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? The question has reasonable context, so I assume the downvote is due to a problem with the answer.

Comment: I have added justification for $(4)$, in case that was a problem.

Answer (score 2):

In discrete mathematics, especially in genereting functions, there is a really nice pattern (exercise: prove  that):
$$\frac{C}{(1-\lambda x)^k} = C \sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\lambda ^n x^n$$
In your case take $t := x^{3k}$. Choosing certain $k$ can be helpful there.